# Tricky interview question about generics, bounded wildcards and getClass()

Tags: java, generics

What is the general principle behind "parameter type compatibility" (whatever we can call it)?

```
Class<Base> cls1 = new Derived().getClass();            // ERR

Class<? extends Base> cls2 = new Derived().getClass();  // OK

Class<? super Base> cl3 = new Derived().getClass();      // ERR     


Class<Base> cls4 = new Base().getClass();               // ERR      

Class<? extends Base> cls5 = new Base().getClass();     // OK

Class<? super Base> cls6 = new Base().getClass();       // ERR
```

**My answer:**

`Class<Base> cls1` in LHS expects *exactly* `Class<Base>` in RHS => `Class<? extends Derived>` is error.

`Class<? extends Base> cls2` as per *PECS* means that anything we get from cls2 (by iterator or (imagine it exists) "get" methods) is Base (so that we can call base methods on what we got). `Class<? extends Derived>` is Base in any case (be it Derived or its subclasses). So it compiles.

`Class<? super Base> cls3` as per *PECS* means that we can always add Base to cls3 by (imagine it exists) "add/put" method - so Collection contains Base or its superclass. `Class<? extends Derived>` can never be Base => Error.

---

I understand that `new Derived().getClass()` returns `Class<? extends Derived>`, likewise `new Base().getClass()` returns `Class<? extends Base>`.

I understand that `List<? extends String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();` is OK and why.

I understand *array covariance* and *covariant return types*.

But the above set of test problems beats me - I cannot formulate rules that my reasoning shall be guided by.

P.S. PECS answers don't help me because mainly they view the problem in terms of "can I add or put or both into a collection/object". The focus of my question is on references compatibility.

Comment: See: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given an expression of type `T`, `expression.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends T>`, because `expression` is either a `T` or a subclass of `T`. (Strictly, it is a `Class<? extends |T|>`, where `||` denotes erasure; but that's unnecessary detail in the context of this question, where none of the values of `T` are generic).

Given this fact, `expression.getClass()` is neither `Class<T>` nor `Class<? super T>`, in the same way that a `List<? extends Number>` isn't a `List<Number>` or a `List<? super Number>`.

It doesn't matter if `something` is `new SpecificSomething()`: that's not a `Class<SpecificSomething>`, because the fact it's a new instance (and that it's guaranteed to be exactly a `SpecificSomething`) isn't taken into account: `new SpecificSomething()` is an expression of type `SpecificSomething`, so `getClass()` returns a `Class<? extends SpecificSomething>`.

Comment: The last paragraph of the answer explains my last 3 examples, the middle paragraph of the answer explains my first 3 examples. Now I understood the answer! Thanks!

Comment: "Given an expression of type `T`, `expression.getClass()` returns `Class<? extends T>`" Actually, it returns `Class<? extends |T|>`, where `|T|` is the erasure of `T`.

Comment: @newacct whilst strictly true, the difference is unnecessary detail in the context of the question, where all of the values of T are not generic.